# TFS: Keeping history while formatting document

Tags: c#, c++, pretty-print

Currently, the developers of my team format their source code (C++, C+, stored in MS's TFS 2012) manually. We are now considering to use Visual Studio's auto formatting option (probably with Uncrustify as the pretty print engine). The idea would be to make sure that nobody has any outgoing changes, and then to format the whole code base and to commit the result. From then on, we would integrate automatic formatting into our workflow.

However, our fear is that we will afterwards not be able to easily find out who has done the last changes on a particular line of code using Source Control/Annotate (that information is often quite useful, e.g. for asking the according developer about that code).

So here are my two questions:

a) Does anybody have experience with introducing auto-formatting into a team's workflow (given an already existing and quite large code base)? Are there any best practices for this?

b) In particular: Is there any way to format our complete code base without loosing the history information? I could e.g. imagine a tool which would keep track of where each line has gone after formatting, and to adjust TFS's history such that that information is preserved. However, I haven't found anything like that by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotation will indeed be 'screwed up' by pretty-printing the whole project. There are no tools that I know of that can work around that.

A way to get the least amount of history issues is to have each developer prettify a method when he is making changes to it to add functionality or solve a bug, this will take time to propagate the whole code base, but it's the only way I know of.